# Threads communicating without locking

Tags: c#, locking

If I can guarantee myself that only one method in my entire app will ever write to a certain variable, then may I allow other methods in my app to safely read that value ?

If so, can I get away that stunt without locking the variable ?

In this context, what I'm doing (or, trying to do, or want to do) is for one method in one thread to put a value into the variable, and then other methods in other threads will read that value and make decisions.

A very nice option would be to lock against writes, while allowing reads.

Looked here [MSDN page on lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and didn't see a way to do that.

Comment: Read while writing is not the best idea. You can read mess, when object is already updating.

Comment: @Kamil Yes, correct. I have a second check on a different item after I read this one.

Comment: @Kamil - out of curiosity, do you have a source for that?  I would think a reader could get either the new value or the old value but not some kind of "in-between" value.

Comment: Have a look at [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)

Comment: @EricPetroelje: See Marc Gravell's answer. The problem is when an update in not atomic. For example, if the updated value is an int, then no problem. If the updated value is a struct made up of several ints (for example, a point class), then it could be a real problem. This is the "tearing" Marc refers to.

Comment: or indeed [Joe Duffy's Weblog](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2006/02/08/ThreadsafetyTornReadsAndTheLike.aspx) /cc @Matt

Comment: @Matt - ok, that makes perfect sense.  Seems that most "simple" types or references are safe though (as per the C# spec)

Comment: @EricPetroelje its possible, that some bigger object, like array or struct may be read as "something between old and new". I don't have source for that information, its just logical for me.

Comment: @Eric **changing a reference** is indeed guaranteed to be atomic and safe; the language guarantees that. If, however, the code updated **properties** of an existing object: bad things can happen without synchronisation. If you have a **reference** to an **immutable** class, then you are pretty safe to change the reference at any time... **BUT** all callers must **PROMISE** to take a snapshot of the reference **ONCE** and then use the snapshot. No `int x = Foo.X; int y = Foo.Y` - it has to be `var snap = Foo; int x = snap.X; int y = snap.Y;`

Comment: @MarcGravell - thanks, that pretty much matches my understanding of things

Comment: @MarcGravell: Interesting link. I don't think it would have occurred to me that updating a long might not be atomic.

Comment: @EricPetroelje, this part "..._For example, if the updated value is an int, then no problem_...." was important, and I hope correct, because my stuff over here just worked 9,327 times before another bug elsewhere stopped the entire app. This was two separate threads in two separate classes writing and reading an int in a third separate class. Current state of things here: Hooray.  `Thread_A_Method_A_Class_A` does this: `Third_Class.TheCounter++;` while `Thread_B_Method_B_Class_B` does this: `CurrentCount = Third_Class.TheCounter;` and then uses `CurrentCount` to inform the user.

Comment: @MattBurland, ooops, my previous comment was supposed to be at you; sorry, still learning to navigate these waters.

Answer (score 12):

As always, it depends a lot on the context.

- a variable read in a tight loop may be stored in a register or local cache, so no change will be noticed unless you have a "fence"; `volatile` will fix this, but as a side-effect rather than by explicit intention; most people (including me) can't properly define what `volatile` *means* - so be very careful of using it as a "fix".
- an oversize type (large struct) will not be atomic (for either read or write) - and cannot be handled safely without risk of tearing
- an object or value might involve multiple sub-values; if they aren't changed atomically, it could cause problems

You *might*, however, find that `Interlocked` solves most of your problems without needing a `lock`. At the same time, an uncontested `lock` is **insanely** fast, and even a contested `lock` is still **alarmingly** fast. Frankly, I'm not sure that it is worth the thought you are giving it: a flat `lock` is almost certainly fast-enough, as long as you do the thinking first **outside** the `lock`, and only `lock` it when you know the changes you want to make.

There is *also* `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, but the number of cases where that actually *improves* performance is slim - in my experience, the simplest approach possible is usually the fastest, meaning either `lock` or `Interlocked`. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is a more complex beast, designed for more complex scenarios, and has a little overhead because of it. Not *massive* amounts, but enough to make it worth looking carefully.

Comment: @EricPetroelje Yes, it applies, because he added the qualification "unless you add a fence", which is exactly what `volatile` does.

Comment: +1 for ... "an uncontested lock is insanely fast, and even a contested lock is still alarmingly fast."

Comment: I just spent awhile on [The MSDN lock page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=VS.100).aspx) and [The MSDN ReaderWriterLockSlim page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) where lot of my time was mainly just _DUH_ ! Would you (or anyone reading) be willing to demonstrate the proper syntax and invocations of the `lock` mechanism for a variable  and three methods in three classes that can read it and write it ? Call them whatever you like;  `Comm.BackGroundRx, SomeButtonClick, xClass.Thread3,  MarcsClass.anyOldVariable` whatever.

Comment: @User.1 `lock`===`Monitor`, not `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, but that's easy: to get it: `lock(someLock) { return theField; }`; to set it: `lock(someLock) { theField = value; }`

Comment: @User.1 yes, about 2 lines above, or on MSDN ;p